# Are e4 rcp context injections slow

Tags: eclipse-rcp, context-injection

I am writing an RCP application in eclipse. When I load my application my application models are loaded from a file in the disk and injected with context.

Using a profiler I noticed that the `inject` method slows me down...

Is this a known issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no they aren't slow.

The first injection of a class which is not already in the context may mean that the class has to be constructed but this is no slower than normal class construction.

I have nearly 800 `@Inject` statements in one of my RCPs and this does not cause any problems.

Comment: Interesting... I will soon try to improve performance of my app. When I will have conclusions I will mark your answer as accepted